# binding service from another app

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-binder

In app, that provide service i have two AIDL files:

```
interface ICountTest {
    oneway void count(in INotifierTest test);
}

interface INotifierTest {
   oneway void notify(int count);
}
```

Basically i want to count till `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in `for` loop and then give this value to notifier, so he could show it visually in other app

For this i have a service

xml:

```
<service android:name=".service.TestService"
    android:process=".remote"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="TestService.START_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

(*I've added intent filter to try start it from different approach*)

java:

```
public class TestService extends Service{

   private ICountTest.Stub mBinder;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       mBinder = new ICountTest.Stub() {
           @Override
           public void count(INotifierTest notifier) throws   RemoteException {
               int k = 0;
               for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
                   k = i;
               }
               notifier.notify(k);
           }
       };
   }

   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return mBinder;
   }
}
```

In my `MainActivity` class i've overriden `notify` method:

```
private INotifierTest.Stub mINotifierTest = new INotifierTest.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void notify(int count) throws RemoteException {
       final String result = String.valueOf(count);
       Log.d("aidl_test", result);
       MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
    }
};
```

I'm calling `count` method in `onServiceConnected`:

```
 private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        mCountTest = ICountTest.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
        try {
            Log.d("aidl_test", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            mCountTest.count(mINotifierTest);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {

    }
};
```

But when i need to run it from another app, for example, like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.xxx.xxx", "com.xxx.xxxx.service.TestService"));
getActivity().bindService(i, mServiceConntection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I need to provide my own `ServiceConnection` class, which will override needed functionality, i'm getting binder in it, but basically i have only class name for needed interface and therefore, i can't do nothing with it.
I've also tried to just `startService` but, logically, it won't work.

I think i'm doing something really wrong, please help me to understand.

My goal is : to run `count` method from `TestService` binder in another application, and see `Toast` and `Log` with result.

**EDIT:** I've ried to create same AIDL files with the same package and code as in first app, and using them, but it doesn't work.

**EDIT:** Wow, it was my fault, i've just overriden not `INotifierTest.Stub`, but just `INotifierTest`, **thanks to all for the help**

Comment: you just need the original aidl file to be included in your second app, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: @pskink So, basically, i've just copy pasted them from first app, then i've also have overriden notify in my second app, have gotten ICountTest interface from iBinder, and invoked count method, but it doesn't call notify at any time

Comment: is SecondService#onBind called at all?

Comment: @pskink there is no second service, service from the first app binded, yes, code provided in question

Comment: @Selvin, yes, i just wanted to spend some time, to see if it's working async

Comment: @pskink, i've edited my question, i have some strange behavior in second app

Comment: so you are extending `android.os.IInterface` you have to extend the `Stub` - not `INotifierTest` but `INotifierTest.Stub`

Comment: @pskink, yes, i've done this, thanks, it was my mistake

Comment: you are welcome, nobody's perfect